# load html in browser view in Blackberry4.6 os version

Tags: java, blackberry

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [load html on Blackberry4.6 os version](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9991482/load-html-on-blackberry4-6-os-version)

Hi I'm new in Blackberry app development i want to load HTML in browser field.. I'm able to load HTML for version 5 ,and 6 and more but it not loading in OS version 4

plz tell me how to load this HTML on Blackberry OS version4.6 i m using Eclipsed to developing application on 5 and 6 works properly but in 4.6 not plz tell me how to write. Code for this or any specific change in code or we cant load HTML in OS version 4.6?

```
BrowserField mybroBrowserField=new BrowserField();

add(mybroBrowserField);
mybroBrowserField.displayContent(
"<html><body><h1>hello world! This blackbery apps</h1>   </body></html>",  
"http://localhost");
```

this code apply for 5 and more than 5 version but not work for OS version 4